# Не работает <audio> в мобильных Chrome и Firefox под Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, html, html5, google-chrome, firefox

```html
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Gimn_Sovetskogo_Soyuza_%281977_Vocal%29.oga" autoplay controls></audio>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6w0a26x6

---

Xiaomi Redmi 4A (*Android 6.0.1*).

- Фиддл НЕ работает в **Chrome 59.0.3071.125** и **Firefox 54.0.1** (показывает, что как бы музыка воспроизводится, но звука нет)

> Заходил также с них на ВК и Яндекс.Музыка — глухо.

- Фиддл работает в **Yandex Browser 17.4**

---

Explay Pulsar (*Android 4.4.2*)

- Фиддл работает в во всех вышеуказанных браузерах

---

С чем это связано и можно ли как-то это обойти?

Comment: Вы про `autoplay` или про то, что аудио вообще не воспроизводится, даже если вручную воспроизведение запускать?

Comment: @Visman , про `autoplay` я нагуглил, что он с некоторой версии Chrome не работает. Аудио вообще не воспроизводится, даже если запускать вручную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, телефон давно не перезагружался — помогла обычная перезагрузка.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/184409)

Comment: @Spawn, это и есть ответ: перезагрузить телефон — видно какие-то обновки стали частично, некорректно или требовали перезагрузки.

Answer (score 1):

Это может быть связано с форматом аудио записи, необходимо поиграть с разными форматами, либо добавить src на различные форматы аудио записи, т.к. некоторые браузеры могут работать только с определенным аудио форматом.